# Convert from YYYYddd to date format

Tags: r, date

**I have a df that has a date column "date" like:**

2016001
2016002
..
..
2016366 (this is a leap year)

**How do I convert these to:**
1/1/2016
1/2/2016
..
..
12/31/2016

Comment: Why are you working with such date formats?

Comment: `as.POSIXct(c("2016001", "2016002", "2016366"), format="%Y%j")`

Comment: @HubertL Why not post this as an answer?  Also he wants to output in a different format.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's the default system date that comes off of the hardware I'm pulling from unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, I just didn't have time to make a real answer then

Answer (score 4):

You can use base R function `strptime()` which is used in `as.POSIXct()` to parse a date to a `POSIXct` object. For YYYYddd the format is `%Y%j`:

```
p <- strptime(c("2016001", "2016002", "2016366"), format="%Y%j", tz="UTC")
p
[1] "2016-01-01 UTC" "2016-01-02 UTC" "2016-12-31 UTC"
```

Then if you want to display like 1/1/2016 1/2/2016 .. .. 12/31/2016, you can use `paste()`:

```
paste(p$mon+1, p$mday, p$year+1900, sep="/")
[1] "1/1/2016"   "1/2/2016"   "12/31/2016"
```

Comment: Or in place of the `paste(...)` in the last line of code: `format(p, "%m/%d/%Y")`